# Struggling with a basic part of python (checking whether a variable equals an input)

Tags: python

I am a self taught Python enthusiast who has this snippet of code as seen below.

```
#Insert variables here#
password = 123
username = 123
#———————————-—————————#

import time

def log_in():
    user = input("Username: ")
    if user = username:         # Here is a problem
        print("user correct")
        passl = input("Password: ")

Q1 = input("Log In?: (y/n) ")
if Q1 == ('y'):
    log_in()
else:
    print("5hutting Down")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()
```

[(Snippet of this code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t83jM.png)

I want it to `print("user correct")` once it has confirmed that `user == username` but I have completely forgotten how to do so and because I have not coded Python in a while its hard to use correct terminology to make accurate searches as I've been trying to do. Hoping one of you guys can help!

The line in question:

```
if user == username:
```

I am unsure what syntax i need to be using.

Comment: The code snippet seems to be doing what you want. What error message do you get ?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is right but the semantic is not.

You want to compare the *number* (`123`) with a *string* (`"123"`).

Instead of

```
password = 123
username = 123
```

use

```
password = "123"
username = "123"
```

because the `input()` function returns a *string*.

Comment: @Jaco No, Python 3 does not do any implicit conversions when comparing things. An int is never equal to a string.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet already does that, with one correction. Your `username` variable is a number, while the `input()` function returns a string. So, it will never be `user == username`. Two possible choices: Either change the beginning to

```
username = '123'
```

or change the `if` to `user == int(username)`

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet looks fine to me. Actually, there is no problem with types here, because `input()` does not necessarily return a `string`. If the user enters 123, `input()` will return an `integer`.

```
ActivePython 2.7.14.2717 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 18 2017, 05:08:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = input('username?')
username?123
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
>>>
```

However, it would make more sense to query the username and the password simultaneously and compare the input using `==`. Note that `=` is used for assignment, while `==` is used to compare two values.

```
user = input('Enter username')
pwd = input('Enter password')
if user == username and pwd == password:
    print "Logged in!"
```